# Current application pool name

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, application-pool

I am trying to get the current application pool name of a web application.
I googled a lot and I found several ways to do it but none of them seems to work for me
This is one of my implementations:

```
   private static string GetCurrentApplicationPoolId()
    {
        string virtualDirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        virtualDirPath = virtualDirPath.Substring(4);
        int index = virtualDirPath.Length + 1;
        index = virtualDirPath.LastIndexOf("-", index - 1, index - 1);
        index = virtualDirPath.LastIndexOf("-", index - 1, index - 1);
        virtualDirPath = "IIS://localhost/" + virtualDirPath.Remove(index);
        DirectoryEntry virtualDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(virtualDirPath);
        return virtualDirEntry.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

I get as an error: `Unknown error (0x80005000)`

Comment: what line of code causes that error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Control panel - program features - turn on off - look for IIS 6 compatibily and check everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `HttpContext` in place use this:

```cs
 HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["APP_POOL_ID"]
```

If not use this:

```cs
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
  "APP_POOL_ID", 
  EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664278/how-to-get-application-pool-name-through-code-c-asp-net)