# Get Web hostname in Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've been searching for a way to get the hostname of the web application in the Startup class of my asp.net core 2.0 app.  Specifically, in the Configure method I would like to dynamically set a service property based on the hostname.
For instance, I need to know if the host is running as http://servername/myapp  or https://externalhost.com/myapp

Thank you for any help

Comment: There is no difference between the two.  Your app could technically run as both.  Additionally, with an external DNS name, it's not something a server may know at all, but can definitely serve from (highly likely it's unaware of the dns name).

Comment: The issue I am having is in the in Configure method, I am injecting a log4net configuration file.   Being that I have two application pool workers running (internal access, external access),  I think they are fighting over the log file.   So my thought was on startup,  if host name is {whatever}, use  my.config,   else  use my-internal.config

Comment: As Erik Philips mentioned, you can't know in the Startup-class, which Uri is/will be used, because you can be redirected and have several Dns-Entries for your site, but you can use a action-filter for the Request to get used Uri.

Comment: This won't solve it any portable way, @Nikolaus. Different hostnames may point to the same application pool/instance

Comment: @DagBaardsen I wrote the comment, before I read, that the Loading of the File is the issue .

Comment: @Nikolaus, ah, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot distinguish between hostnames, but on Application Pool identities.
Use this call to distinguish between identities:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Comment: Can this be used in the Startup.cs?

Comment: Yes it can. Definitely!

Comment: Dag, thanks!  This would definitely work, but it led me to another similar approach discussed [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664278/how-to-get-application-pool-name-through-code-c-asp-net)

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_POOL_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664278/how-to-get-application-pool-name-through-code-c-asp-net

Comment: Yes, that's a nice one, Joe!